# How to fix Cors error message on api call nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I`m trying to set up cors for my domain and subdomain but its doesnt work. Can anyone suggest me what should I change on my code

```
const whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://admin.example1.com']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

But when I try this its say "Not allowed by CORS" everywhere.

Comment: Have you checked this page? In addition to setting headers, you might have to enable CORS on the backend as well. https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node

Answer (score -1):

Your server is returning the error message you defined in your callback when the domain is not in the `whitelist`. Make sure that your whitelist entries are correct